# Creating a div style which shows new div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make an

```
<a href=#divstyle> CLICK HERE </a>
```

and when a href is pressed I want to show new page, without refreshing.

New page = new texts,  new layouts,  it's  like new page but the same code the same background.

How can this be achieved?

image of what I want to do:

First, initial code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfAoW.png
Second code when "Glabal Statistics is pressed" https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qFqF.png

second code will show the same layout but new text writen by me,

I want "Global Statistics" to be like "Next Button"

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var pages = $('#container p'),
    current = 0;
  var currentPage, nextPage;

  $('#container .button').click(function() {
    currentPage = pages.eq(current);
    if ($(this).hasClass('prevButton')) {

      if (current <= 0)
        current = pages.length - 1;
      else
        current = current - 1;
    } else {
      if (current >= pages.length - 1)
        current = 0;
      else
        current = current + 1;
    }
    nextPage = pages.eq(current);
    pages.hide();
    nextPage.show();
  }).filter('.nextButton').click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="colw_3 spec-l border-right">
    <p></p>
    <p><strong><em><font color="white">Nickname</font></em></strong><br>
    </p>
    <p><strong><em><font color="white">Headshoturi</font></em></strong><br>
    </p>
    <p><strong><em><font color="white">Banditi&nbsp;Ucisi</font></em></strong><br>
    </p>
    <p><strong><em><font color="white">Ucideri</font></em></strong><br>
    </p>
    <p><strong><em><font color="white">Rucsac</font></em></strong><br>
    </p>
    <p><em><strong><font color="white">Sloturi&nbsp;folosite la&nbsp;rucsac</font></strong></em><br>
    </p>
  </div>
  <!-- END col_6 -->

  <div class="colw_3 paddbott100 spec-r">
    <p></p>
    <p><strong><font color="white"><?php echo $Username ?></font></strong><br>
    </p>
    <p><strong><font color="white"><?php echo $Headshots ?></font></strong><br>
    </p>
    <p><strong><font color="white"><?php echo $BanditsKilled ?></font></strong><br>
    </p>
    <p><strong><font color="white"><?php echo $Murders ?></font></strong><br>
    </p>
    <p><strong><font color="white"><?php echo $Backpack ?></font></strong><br>
    </p>
    <p><strong><font color="white"><?php echo $BackpackSlotsUsed ?></font></strong><br>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is this possible? what i want to try. I need to add new `<div class="colw_3 spec->`  because, this is the "second" page which i want to add.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap each section with a container div:

```
#containerone {
    display:block;
}

#containertwo {
    display:none;
}
```

Then create a javascript function that changes the first container to display:none; and the second to display:block; - and assign it to an event listener.

Hope that helps!